# TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers' using pandas to combine multiple excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to combine multiple excel sheets using Python.  However when I ran this script a few months ago it worked without any issues, now I am receiving the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "P:\2018\218143\GIS\Working_HBK_ASE_Project\SUE_QLData\Python\SUEGISPrep.py", line 15, in 
data_xlsA1 = pd.read_excel(r'\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4296_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'Schedule and QLA Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'

here is the code...

```
`import pandas as pd

skprws = range(0, 3)
datatype = {"Task\nOrder": str,"Contract \nRequest\nNumber": str, "Actual \nNorthing": float, "Actual \nEasting": float, "Proposed Northing": float, "Proposed Easting": float, "Ground Elevation": float, "Top of Utility": float, "Depth": float, "Rim Elevation": float, "Depth (1)": float, "Invert (1)": float, "Depth (2)": float, "Invert (2)": float, "Depth (3)": float, "Invert (3)": float, "Depth (4)": float, "Invert (4)": float, "Depth (5)": float, "Invert (5)": float, "MP \nStart": float, "MP \nEnd": float}
conversions= {"Request #": int, "Priority": int, "SUE Contract Number": int, "Request Contract\nNumber": int, "FWAR\nNumber": int}
data_xlsA1 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4296_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'Schedule and QLA Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsA2 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4297_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'Schedule and QLA Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsA3 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4415_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'Schedule and QLA Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsA4 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4700_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'Schedule and QLA Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsA5 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\MM Formatted-LG_HBK_ARD_4570_LookAheadSchedule_02242023.xlsx', 'Schedule and QLA Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsB1 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4296_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'QLB Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsB2 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4297_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'QLB Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsB3 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4415_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'QLB Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsB4 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4700_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'QLB Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsB5 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\MM Formatted-LG_HBK_ARD_4570_LookAheadSchedule_02242023.xlsx', 'QLB Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsC1 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS`Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4296_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'QLC Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsC2 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4297_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'QLC Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsC3 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4415_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'QLC Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsC4 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\LG_ASE_TAS_4700_LookAheadSchedule.xlsx', 'QLC Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)
data_xlsC5 = pd.read_excel(r'\\chicagostorage2017\public\2018\218143 - ISTHA SUE\05 - GIS\05.09 - GIS Source Data\MM Formatted-LG_HBK_ARD_4570_LookAheadSchedule_02242023.xlsx', 'QLC Results', headers= 1, skiprows= skprws, index_col=None, dtype=datatype,converters=conversions)

dfA = pd.concat([data_xlsA1, data_xlsA2, data_xlsA3, data_xlsA4, data_xlsA5])
dfB = pd.concat([data_xlsB1, data_xlsB2, data_xlsB3, data_xlsB4, data_xlsB5])
dfC = pd.concat([data_xlsC1, data_xlsC2, data_xlsC3, data_xlsC4, data_xlsC5])

dfA.to_excel(r'P:\2018\218143\GIS\Data\TBL\Excel_In\LG_ASE_TAS_Combined_QLA_LookAhead.xlsx', encoding= 'utf-8', index=False)
dfB.to_excel(r'P:\2018\218143\GIS\Data\TBL\Excel_In\LG_ASE_TAS_Combined_QLB.xlsx', encoding= 'utf-8', index=False)
dfC.to_excel(r'P:\2018\218143\GIS\Data\TBL\Excel_In\LG_ASE_TAS_Combined_QLC.xlsx', encoding= 'utf-8', `your text`index=False)

print("Files Constructed")  
`
```

I tired to change the word "headers" to "header".  When I did this I didn't get an error however not all the spreadsheet ended combined.  Only the first one was in the new table.  I did not write this code and am very very inexperienced with programing.

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to have a look at the pandas documentation. It all depends on what output you want. The first error is solved by changing headers to header. the second one might involve the parameters of the pandas.concat function. It depends, for example, on which axis you intend to concat your objects, if you want to ignore the index... It is however hard from my side to solve your problem as there is no further description of what is your problem, and no visualisation of it.

here is the link to access the documentation for the resolved mistake:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Here is the link if you wanna understand and modify your code in a way that suits you the most:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: This may be more of a comment than a real answer though.